# how to convert an object with array values to strings and insert in my html

Tags: javascript, express

Below is the code i want to pass on to my errors array an send the values to my client side template in html

```
{
    "email": [
        "user with this email already exists."
    ]
    
}
```

i want something like this

```
"user with this email already exists"
```

i want to ignore the property name and just take the value which is  the strings. i have tried using `response.json()` to convert it but it still returns error of `response.json is not a function`

Comment: "*it but it still returns error of `response.json is not a function`*" Ok, but why haven't you included "*it*" (a.k.a., your code, as a [mre]) so we might be able to point out where you've run afoul in this approach? [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = {
    "email": [
        "user with this email already exists."
    ]   
};

console.log(Object.values(data).flat());
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you could try something like this:

```js
let errors = {
    "email": [
        "user with this email already exists.",
        "error 2",
    ],
    "password": [
      "password is too weak",
    ]
};
let errorsStr = "";

for (let key in errors) {
  for (let error of errors[key]) {
    errorsStr += error + "; ";
  }
}

console.log(errorsStr);
```

Or alternative solution:

```js
let errors = {
    "email": [
        "user with this email already exists.",
        "error 2",
    ],
    "password": [
      "password is too weak",
    ]
};
let errorsArray = Object.values(errors).flat();
let errorsStr = errorsArray.join("; ");

console.log(errorsStr);
```